# Is it necessary to declare Singleton to access a single object in my all activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, singleton, serializable

I am building a menu from which the user can select items. They can edit their selections whenever necessary. The singleton would be a class containing the list of all selectable items. Whenever new activities are opened, the singleton would have the correct state of all items.

The reason I am asking this is because implementing Serializable creates a new instance (albeit almost identical) of the item.

Comment: I did not clear question. Singleton's purpose is to control object creation, limiting the number of obejcts to one only.

Comment: You can use singleton and another option is to create it in your Main activity and define BroadcaseReceiver that will be triggered each time a selection is done on one of the other activities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use a singleton for this.  It would be something like:

```
public class MenuData {

    private static MenuData instance;

    private boolean isItemASelected;

    public static MenuData getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new MenuData();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean isItemASelected() {
        return isItemASelected;
    }

    public void setItemASelected(boolean itemASelected) {
        isItemASelected = itemASelected;
    }

}
```

However I wouldn't recommend this.  This data will only be around for as long as your Application is in memory.  As soon as your app gets killed by Android all the variables will be cleared and the state will have been lost.

If your menu items are constant then I'd recommend using SharedPreferences to store the state.  If they are dynamic then use the SQL database.  This way the options are persisted even if your app gets killed.